# randomize string without duplicate c++

Tags: c++

I am trying to convert the written python line into c++ `key = ''.join([secrets.choice(t) for _ in range(20)])` I have already have the join function into c++ , but I would like to add this feature `[secrets.choice(t) for _ in range(20)]` into c++ . however I have my shuffle function , but it only works with int, but I want to make it work on my actual issue strings

```c
void Common::shuffle(int* dst) {
    int sz, pos, i, src[50];
    for (i = 0; i < sizeof(src) / sizeof(*src); i++)
        src[i] = i + 1;
    sz = 50;
    for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        pos = rand() % sz;
        dst[i] = src[pos];
        src[pos] = src[sz - 1];
        sz--;
    }
}
```

```
int main(){
    std::vector<std::string> seq{ reverse.ascii_lowercase() , reverse.ascii_uppercase() , reverse.digits() , reverse.punctuation() };
    std::cout << reverse.join(reverse.shuffle(seq), "--") << std::endl;
    std::cin.get();
}
```

Comment: Is the line you're trying to convert written in Python?  It looks that way, but you ought to say so explicitly so that people won't have to guess.

Comment: I am trying to convert the written python line into c++

Comment: I suspect this is a homework question...

Comment: The best you can do is to stream whatever you've got to something like `sha256_sum` (or 512 if you're paranoid) (or be serious and link to openssl) and be done with it.